# Round up to the nearest multiple of .5 python

Tags: python

How do I round up to the nearest increment of .5? Say I have

```
a=2.3
```

and want to declare b as 2.5 taking a as an input and rounding up to the nearest .5

Comment: Try `round(a * 2) / 2`

Comment: I only want it to round up though. That also round down if a=2.2

Comment: What if you do something like, `int(a)+0.5` (for a >= 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `math.ceil` and simple arithmetic operations to get where you need:

```
import math
a = 2.3
rounded_a = math.ceil(a * 2) / 2
print(rounded_a) # 2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add what's missing.

```
a += -a % .5
```